# Rolling Count of Previous Defaults for a customer

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I would like to generate the amount of defaults/late payements a customer has had previous to a transaction. 
For example:

```
Customer   Late  Count
A          YES      0
B          NO       0
A          NO       1
B          YES      0
B          NO       1
A          YES      1
A          YES      2
```

The first transaction for each customer would have a count of 0. Every transaction after that would have the count of late payments for that customer previous to the current transaction. The last transaction has a count of 2 because A was late on two previous transactions.

Answer (score 1):

In your case , you may need `groupby` with `cumsum` and `shift`

```
df.Late.eq('YES').groupby(df.Customer).apply(lambda x : x.cumsum().shift().fillna(0)).astype(int)
Out[501]: 
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    0
4    1
5    1
6    2
Name: Late, dtype: int32
```